# Where is the autocomplete function for user/addressfield/autocomplete?

Tags: 7, entities

I searched but I cannot find the autocomplete function for addressfield module.
The path of this autocomplete function is user/addressfield/autocomplete.

So I need the file that declare this function.
Thanks!

Comment: are you using any additional module along with addressfield module for autocomplete feature, if so please mention the module name in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using the [Commerce Admin Order Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_admin_order_advanced) module.  This is was providing the autocomplete.